# select only the element is same div with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="to-click">
<h1>click me</h1>
</div>
<div class="to-show">
<p>this text will appear when clicked</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="to-click">
<h1>click me</h1>
</div>
<div class="to-show">
<p>this text will appear when clicked</p>
</div>
</div>
```

i have unknown number of divs, each div has an element to be clicked and an element to be toggled

```
$('.to-show').hide();
$('.to-click').click(function () {
$('.to-show').toggle();
});
```

i want when i click on the first H1 only the first p is showed, and when the second h1 is clicked the second p is showed and so on

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are fine, but I would recommend a slightly different approach, using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

This version will work even if you add something in between `.to-click` and `.to-show`, if they're reverted or even if they're not siblings. This way it doesn't depend that much on your HTML structure, as long as they have a common ancestor.

**Demo:**

```js
$('.to-show').hide();
$('.to-click').on('click', function () {
  $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.to-show').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="to-click">
    <h1>click me</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="to-show">
    <p>this text will appear when clicked</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="to-click">
    <h1>click me</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="to-show">
    <p>this text will appear when clicked</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's next() selector to identify the next to-show class and toggle it:

```js
$('.to-show').hide();
$('.to-click').click(function() {
  $(this).next(".to-show").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="to-click">
    <h1>click me</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="to-show">
    <p>this text will appear when clicked</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="to-click">
    <h1>click me</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="to-show">
    <p>this text will appear when clicked</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't edit the divs to give them IDs you can use the item you clicked on to find the subsequent item to toggle. Something like this:

```
$('to-click').click(function() {
    // close any existing shown items
    // comment this out if you want multiple items at the same time.
    $('.to-show').hide();  

    var $self = $(this); // this will be the element clicked
    // find the parent then select the '.to-show'
    var $to_show = $self.parent().find('.to-show')
    $to_show.toggle();
}
```